# Algorithm better than Greedy for Dominating set

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, approximation

I just want to know that whether there is an algorithm better than the Greedy Algorithm for [Dominating set](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/kuhn/teaching/netalg/lectures/chapter7.pdf). I know that Greedy gives [$O(\log(\Delta))-approx$](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/kuhn/teaching/netalg/lectures/chapter7.pdf) and we can not do something better than $log \Delta$ for dominating set unless P=NP. But I came across [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539704444750?journalCode=smjcat) for $k-$ set cover which gives some improvement over $H_k$-approx for $k$-set cover. Is there something like for Dominating set also?

Comment: Can you make the question self-contained to describe what kind of improvement you are referring to, so we don't have to read that paper to understand what you have in mind?  Also, it sounds like you haven't accurately summarized the state of approximability results; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Algorithms_and_computational_complexity.  Also, what research have you done?  Have you started with the papers cited by Wikipedia, and then looked at other papers that cite them (using Google Scholar) to see if there are any more recent results that narrow the constant-factor gap?

Comment: We prefer that references fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/); in particular, it's helpful to list the title of the paper, the authors, where it was published, and if available, a link to a free (non-paywalled) PDF.  Thank you!